# Getting error An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details. Reload 

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Hi I am working on Blazor server side and getting "An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details. Reload " message. i tried to see the console but nothing is there. Attached screen of console.

[image]

Comment: Have you modified the default CSS that comes with a new blazor project? Because you may have removed the classes that hide the error display. Does the application still work despite the error message? If so the CSS is 99% the problem.

Comment: Yes, i have deleted default css class

Comment: You deleted the default CSS file entirely? That's your issue then.

Comment: It's my issue too. An honest mistake since we started with the template. This is a problem solving site where "my issue" can be solved.

Comment: This is poor design on blazor's part. They should hide that div with inline CSS. Putting that functionality in an external stylesheet that will be modified by users is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 43):

Actually I had the same problem but the solution is with site.css it's contain some lines you need to add it to your css file

```
#blazor-error-ui{
 background: lightyellow;
 bottom: 0;
 box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 display: none;
 left: 0;
 padding: 0.6rem 1.25rem 0.7rem 1.25rem;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1000;}
#blazor-error-ui .dismiss {
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0.75rem;
 top: 0.5rem;}
```

Comment: At first clearing cache solved this, but when I added these lines this seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did delete this and I also added it back to app.css since I am only using wasm :)

Answer (score 6):

it's not an exception but by removing or not including the `css/site.css` file you removed the styles that hide the error message div.

The `#blazor-error-ui` defaults to `display: none` so by not including or removing it, you're simply just showing the div.

If you include the `#blazor-error-ui` and `#blazor-error-ui .dismiss` sections, you should be fine, if you didn't want to include the css/site.css file that was generated with your project. You mentioned you deleted it, here is what mine looks like for a new default project:

```css
@import url('open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css');

html, body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

a, .btn-link {
    color: #0366d6;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1b6ec2;
    border-color: #1861ac;
}

.content {
    padding-top: 1.1rem;
}

.valid.modified:not([type=checkbox]) {
    outline: 1px solid #26b050;
}

.invalid {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

.validation-message {
    color: red;
}

#blazor-error-ui {
    background: lightyellow;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0.6rem 1.25rem 0.7rem 1.25rem;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

    #blazor-error-ui .dismiss {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0.75rem;
        top: 0.5rem;
    }
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had almost the same problem, but not because I deleted *per se* the two `#blazor-error-ui` rules cited in Noor's response. Wanting to use the same components for both server- and WASM-based versions of my app, I initially split the (server-based) app into two projects, one bare-boned with `Pages/_Host.cshtml` and a few other critical files, the other project with everything else—including all CSS files. The symptoms described in the original post appeared, but only when the user switched languages and only momentarily.

My remedy was to create a separate CSS file with the two `#blazor-error-ui` rules, name it `Host.css`, and place it in `wwwroot/css` of the bare-boned project. Then I added the following line to the `<head>` element of `_Host.cshtml`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Host.css" />
```

(The name and location of the new CSS file aren't important, as long as they're in the project with `_Host.cshtml` and the `<link>`'s `href` attribute correctly identifies the file.)

Of course, this approach would also work with a single-project app, allowing you to change or remove other CSS files with reckless abandon.

Comment: For me clearing cache worked, as I have been making many minor changes which produced this error

Answer (score 0):

My issue was similar to @Rich Armstrong. Our Blazor application is a WASM app and the IIS environment has https://localhost/blah/blah/Index.

In a file called index.html, which is located in the project under 'wwwroot' folder, there is an XML tag `<base href="/" />`. The tag needed to be `<base href="/blah/blah/" />`

where `/blah/blah/` is the pathing in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually had this twice in my blazor server app - very useless error but essentially the webserver crashes - and the app can't connect.

1st time: I was injecting a service, and the service was not in the added in Startup.cs

```
@inject MyShiftService myShiftService
```

But I had failed to put Startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped<MyShiftService>();
```

2nd time:  I was setting a variable (buttonText) in OnInitializedAsync, but that variable was being blocked by an if statement on a url parameter -  (so buttonText was not being rendered on the page).